# Pointers and Arrays of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I understand this is a commonly asked question, but i've still yet managed to find a solution.

I have create an array of a struct path called location
    path `location[numLevels*levelSize];`

I am also using a stack of paths called start.

The problem is transferring the proper location in the array to a function, having it create a new path to put in the array, than send it back.

```
bool moveLocationStack(const vector <vector<path> > &spaceStation,const int x,const int y,path   *square){
char c=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).type;
if(c!='#'){
    if(!spaceStation.at(y).at(x).visit and !spaceStation.at(y).at(x).inPath)
        square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).type;
        square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).visit;
        square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).inPath;
        square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).level;
        return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The pointer square should point to the next location of the array sent to it by the function call
I try to be:

```
  if(moveLocationStack(spaceStation,possibleX,possibleY,location[currentLocation])){
    }
```

It has an issue with sending the specific array section i want pointed to indexed by a variable elsewhere in the code currentLocation. If I just write location it works but I'm pretty sure it won't point to the next available space in the array everytime its called even if i increment currentLocations.

Any way to explain this so I can understand the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frantly I don't understand the question, but I can see that this is wrong

```
if(moveLocationStack(spaceStation,possibleX,possibleY,location[currentLocation])){
```

you mean

```
if(moveLocationStack(spaceStation,possibleX,possibleY,&location[currentLocation])){
```

You are passing an address to `moveLocationStack`, so you should use `&location[currentLocation]` not `location[currentLocation]`.

Also it seems like this is wrong

```
    square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).type;
    square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).visit;
    square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).inPath;
    square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).level;
```

surely you mean this

```
    square->type=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).type;
    square->visit=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).visit;
    square->inPath=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).inPath;
    square->level=spaceStation.at(y).at(x).level;
```

or maybe (assuming `square` is a `path*`) this

```
    *square = spaceStation.at(y).at(x);
```

You can copy a struct in one go, you don't have to copy each item in a struct separately.

Comment: Yes i definitely means that when loading square, i dont know why i just wrote that. Okay thanks!! so when i set a variable equal to a pointer right away, such as int *temp; i would set it equal to a variable if were to access it int *temp=&num1

Comment: What if I wanted to pass the entire array in as a argument in case I need more than one path to access off it?

Comment: You cannot pass an array in C++ so you have to pass a pointer the first element. So just replace `&location[currentLocation]` with `location` or even (same thing) `&location[0]`.